# How to get the text between two special symbols(%) in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get the text between two % symbols in a textarea ???  I tried using jquery .keypress() event and got the result upto a certain level. But the keypress event will not get triggered if i delete or press backspace. If i go with .keyup() or .keydown(), how to detect the "%" character ... Here is what i tried out

```
var flag = false,
string = '';
$("#target").keypress(function(event) {
//  console.log(event,String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
if ( event.which == 37 ) {  
 if(flag === true){
  flag = false;      
  alert("REsult: "+ string.slice(1));
 }      
 flag= true;
}

//  console.log(flag, event.which);
if(flag === true){
 string = string + String.fromCharCode(event.which);
}
 console.log(string);   
});
```

Here is the [bin](http://jsbin.com/uyufiw/2/edit)

Am i going in the right path or is there any other better way... Please help me with your suggestions

Comment: `keypress` will also not be triggered by cut/paste from the edit menu or context menu, or by drag'n'drop changes. Using `blur` handles all of those, but obviously not until the user leaves the field. What do you intend to actually do with the text, assuming you manage to grab it?

Comment: I'm trying to show a dropdown menu based on the text between the placeholders(%) like an autocomplete. but i dont want to use any plugins as of now

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
var test_str = "text to get % Other text.... migh have % s ...";
var start_pos = test_str.indexOf('%') + 1;
var end_pos = test_str.indexOf('%',start_pos);
var text_to_get = test_str.substring(start_pos,end_pos)
alert(text_to_get);
```

Comment: Even this wont works out. please see the comments for @Egor answer. I want things to happen when the user starts typing with a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i get the text between two % symbols in a textarea ???

```
var matches = /%([^%]*)%/.exec($("#target").val());
var result = matches ? matches[1] : null;
```

Comment: I dont want to match like this. Since this fails if % is present in my textarea... Actually, i'm trying to open up a dropdown when the user starts typing with a percentage like "%blah blah.." similar to "@" in tweets

Comment: What about `/%([^%]*)%?/`?